# OAuth2 authentication for Google API with PHP

Tags: google-analytics, google-api-php-client

I need to write a web app for a marketing company which needs to connect to their customers websites to access Google analytics data and store it in their database. 
I follow the example provided by Google at:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api
I created the following Client id at Google API console

```
Client ID:      915242733409.apps.googleusercontent.com
Email address:  915242733409@developer.gserviceaccount.com
Client secret:  xxx
Redirect URIs:  http://thefridgedoors.net/google-analytics/google-api-php-client/examples/analytics/simple.php
JavaScript origins: https://www.thefridgedoors.net
```

My app's authentication looks as follows:

```
/* Start a session to persist credentials */
session_start();

/* Create and configure a new client object */
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google+ PHP Starter Application");
// Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console to generate your
// oauth2_client_id, oauth2_client_secret, and to register your oauth2_redirect_uri.
$client->setClientId('915242733409.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('…');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://thefridgedoors.net/google-analytics/example1.php');
$client->setDeveloperKey('…');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'));
```

However I get the following error:
There wan a general error :

```
Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts?key=AIzaSyALRCwV32b8fAtcvFuaDVwNUxrYrtg51tI: (403) Access Not Configured
```

Any hint on what might be wrong?

Comment: You should reset the API keys that you posted here. I have removed them from your post, but they could have been stolen before I got here and they can still be viewed by SO users with sufficient knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the Analytics API for your project in the [Google APIs Console](http://developers.google.com/console). Open your project, select the **Services** tab, and then click on the switch under the **Status** column for the Analytics API.

P.S. you might want to avoid publishing your client secrets.